# Count number of CCNodes of a certain class on a layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Pretty simple question. I'm working in Objective C (cocos2d) and I'm trying to count the number of a sprites of a certain class are present on the current layer being displayed. For example, I have a class named `Seal` which is a subclass of of `CCNode` and in my current layer I want to count how many instances of type `Seal` are present.

I know how to count the number of children of the layer by doing

```
int numberChildren = [[self children] count];
```

which correctly returns the number of children on the layer. But I just want the number of `Seal`s on my layer. How could I do this? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code which doesn't use an array and hence less memory foot print--

```
NSInteger sealCounter = 0;
for(id item in [self children])     
     if([item isKindOfClass:[Seal class])
         sealCounter++; //After the for loop ends you can know how many Seals you have
```

But if you want to run some actions only on Seals after you count them then storing the items in an array would help you like this:

```
NSMutableArray *sealArray;
for(id item in [self children])     
     if([item isKindOfClass:[Seal class])
         [sealArray addObject:(Seal *)item];//This will hold only seals and you can get the count by simply doing [sealArray count];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using predicate functions, like:

```
NSArray * nodes = [self children];

NSIndexSet * sealSet = [nodes indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[Seal class]];
}];

NSArray * sealArray = [nodes objectsAtIndexes:sealSet];
NSUInteger numberOfSeals = [sealArray count];
```

EDIT:
Actually you don't have to store seals in a new array, you can count them simply:

```
NSUInteger numberOfSeals = [sealSet count];
```